# java code for flex automation using selenium rc

Tags: java, apache-flex, selenium, selenium-rc

Following is a code from http://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/ :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.*;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.FlexUISelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class FlexUISeleniumTest {
    private final static String BASE_URL = "http://www.geocities.com/";
    private final static String PAGE = "paulocaroli/flash/sum.html";
    private Selenium selenium;
    private FlexUISelenium flexUITester;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
            selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore",BASE_URL);
            selenium.start();
            selenium.open(PAGE);
            flexUITester = new FlexUISelenium(selenium, "compareSumFlexObjId");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            selenium.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyFlexAppSumIsCorrect() {
            flexUITester.type("2").at("arg1");
            flexUITester.type("3").at("arg2");
            flexUITester.click("submit");
            assertEquals("5", flexUITester.readFrom("result"));             
    }

}
```

in the line flexUITester = `new FlexUISelenium(selenium, "compareSumFlexObjId");`
Can someone explain to me what is `"compareSumFlexObjId"` . In one website it was given that it is the name of the swf file.

If it is the name of the swf file then in that case where should we place the swf file?should it be placed along with this java code? Or is there another way of writing the above code? The above code is right now giving me error

> "element compareSumFlexObjId not found"

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I'd like to point out that flex-ui-selenium has been in v0.1 since februari 2010. You might want to consider FlexMonkey/FlexMonkium which seems to be more mature.

Comment: yes, i've tried using flexmonkey and flexmonkium, but i want to try automation without using flexmonkey and flexmonkium. are you telling that for the current version of selenium RC, flex-ui-selenium can not be used?

Comment: No, I'm just implying that you may be using an unfinished product that will probably never get finished at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `compareSumFlexObjId` with the swf filename which is loaded into html page.
e.g. if your swf file name is `abc.swf`, replace `compareSumFlexObjId` with `abc`.